# Ошибки LNK2005 и LNK1169

Tags: c++, файлы, проект

Пытаюсь поэкспериментировать с файлами в проекте. Выводит ошибки **LNK2005** и **LNK1169**.
Вот как выглядят сами ошибки:
`LNK2005 "char const * * menus" (?menus@@3PAPEBDA) already defined in main.obj`

`LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found`

Заметил что ошибка эта происходит когда я добавляю в **mainmenu.h** вот этот блок кода

```
const char* menus[] =
{
    "START",
    "RECORDS",
    "OPTIONS"
};
```

а если же я его закомментирую, то ошибка пропадает. Вопрос: почему так происходит?

Вот пожалуйста, все исходные файлы ниже. Тут совсем немного кода.

**main.h**

```
#pragma once

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <conio.h>

enum KEY { UP = 72, DOWN = 80 };

bool gameloop();
```

**mainmenu.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#include "main.h"

const char* menus[] =
{
    "START",
    "RECORDS",
    "OPTIONS"
};

int mainmenu(int list = 0);
```

**window.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class window
{
private:
    const int width = 100;
    const int height = 40;
public:
    window()
    {
        SetConsoleTitleA("game");

        char command[256]; //буфер для текста команды

        //этот алгоритм нужен чтобы создать системную команду
        //"mode con cols=width lines=height"

        const std::string sys = "mode con cols=" + std::to_string(width) + " lines=" + std::to_string(height);
        std::strcpy(command, sys.c_str());

        //конец алгоритма

        system(command);
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "window.h"
#include "mainmenu.h"

int main()
{
    gameloop();

    return 0;
}

bool gameloop()
{
    bool gamestate = true;

    while (gamestate)
    {
        window window;

        mainmenu();

        _getch();
    }

    return true;
}
```

**mainmenu.cpp**

```
#include "mainmenu.h"

int mainmenu(int list)
{
    switch (list)
    {
    case 0:
        cout << *menus[0] << endl;
    case 1:
        cout << *menus[1] << endl;
    case 2:
        cout << *menus[2] << endl;

        switch (_getch())
        {
        case KEY::UP:
            if (list != 0) list--;
            break;
        case KEY::DOWN:
            if (list != 2) list++;
            break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Почему ваш массив неконстантен? Вам нужно иметь возможность его менять?

Comment: Почему вообще вам массив объявлен в заголовочном файле? Почему не в `mainmenu.cpp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы *определяете* (не просто объявляете!) `const char* menus[]` в заголовочном файле.

Потом, при каждом включении этого заголовочного файла в .cpp-файл, в каждом из них оказывается этот массив.

И какой именно из них линкер должен считать верным и почему? Вот он и теряется...

Answer (score 3):

(Точный ответ на вопрос зависит от того, должен ли этот массив быть глобальной *модифицируемой* переменной. Из вашего описания этого не ясно.)

(Не ясно также, нужна ли вам вообще глобальная доступность этого массива. Зачем вы вообще поместили его в заголовочный файл, а не в `mainmenu.cpp`?)

Ваше

```
const char* menus[] =
{
    "START",
    "RECORDS",
    "OPTIONS"
};
```

это определение неконстантной переменной, т.е. этот массив имеет *внешнее связывание*. Если вы включите это в несколько единиц трансляции, то разумеется вы ожидаемо получите множественные определения объекта с внешним связыванием.

- Либо дайте вашему массиву внутреннее связывание

  ```
  const char* const menus[] =
  {
      "START",
      "RECORDS",
      "OPTIONS"
  };
  ```

  или

  ```
  static const char* menus[] =
  {
      "START",
      "RECORDS",
      "OPTIONS"
  };
  ```

  (что, однако, породит отдельную копию этого массива в каждой единице трансляции)
- Либо объявите его `inline`

  ```
  inline const char* menus[] =
  {
      "START",
      "RECORDS",
      "OPTIONS"
  };
  ```
- Либо идите по "классическому" пути: в заголовочном файле только объявление

  ```
  extern const char* menus[];
  ```

  а определение - в одном из файлов реализации.

Я не знаю, нужно ли вы вам менять этот массив или нет, т.е. можно ли его сделать константным. Если можно, то лучше всего скомбинировать первый и второй варианты и сделать

```
    inline extern const char* const menus[] =
    {
        "START",
        "RECORDS",
        "OPTIONS"
    };
```

Разумеется, все это имеет смысл при условии, что объявление массива должно располагаться в заголовочном файле. Из вашего описания не ясно, зачем ему вообще там располагаться.

Comment: я думал намного проще и организованней будет, если я буду включать все свои глобальные переменные в .h файлы. но видимо это не так...........

Comment: @bone_appettit: Это, разумеется, **так**. Но вопрос по-прежнему в том, с чего это вдруг у вас `menus` стало *глобальной* переменной. Зачем `menus` быть глобальной переменной?

Comment: да, вы правы, в main.cpp этот массив совершенно не нужен, я пересмотрел код и только сейчас понял это