# Проблема с инициализацией

Tags: c++, visual-studio, многопоточность

у меня проект состоит из 3-х файлов : 
**Header - с прототипами ф-ций
Source - с функциями
Source1 - с выводом функций на экран**
Проблема в том, что я хочу написать глобальную переменную для всех файлов в Header, (int maxs = 0), а выдает такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слышали что-то об ODR (One Definition Rule)?

Comment: Inline переменную можно впилить

Comment: ничего не понятно но очень интересно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1030886/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-lnk2005-%D0%B8-lnk1169

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите в заголовочном файле объявление

```
extern int maxs;
```

и в *одном* .cpp-файле определение

```
int maxs = 0;
```

Второй вариант - если компилятор понимает свежие стандарты - написать в заголовочном файле

```
inline int maxs = 0;
```

Вариант написать в заголовочном файле

```
static int maxs = 0;
```

приведет к тому, что все будет компилироваться, но в каждом .cpp-файле будет своя переменная `maxs`...